# How can I separate a sentence including withe-space, digit and String?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to separate a sentence 37 37 " " with 3 results like 37 37 ' ' and save each results to 3 varaible.
This is my code

```
public class Graph<T extends Comparable <T>> {
private Vertex<T> head; 
private int size;
private boolean isDirected;     
private boolean hasEdgeValue;  
private T startState;
private List finishedState;
public Graph() {    this(false, false); }
public Graph(boolean isDirected, boolean hasEdgeValue) {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
    finishedState = new LinkedList<T>();
    this.isDirected = isDirected;
    this.hasEdgeValue = hasEdgeValue;
}
public void createGraph(Scanner inFile) {
    T fromVert, toVert;
    T weight; //weight
    while(inFile.hasNext()) {
        fromVert = (T) inFile.next();//save 37 here
        toVert = (T) inFile.next();//save 37 here
        if(hasEdgeValue) { 
            weight = (T) inFile.next(); //save ' '(white-space or a if inpute is "a" here
            insertVertex(fromVert);
            insertVertex(toVert);
            insertEdge(fromVert, toVert, weight);
            if(!isDirected) {
                insertEdge(toVert, fromVert, weight);
            }
        }
        else {
            insertVertex(fromVert);
            insertVertex(toVert);
            insertEdge(fromVert, toVert, null);
            if(!isDirected) {
                insertEdge(toVert, fromVert, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

this is my input data

14 37  " "

37 37  "a"

37 37  "b"

37 37  "c"

37 37  "d"

37 37  "e"

I used useDelimeter but it's not working please help me
Result should be fromVert is 37, toVert 37, weight is ' ' if input is 37 37 " "

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code here. How are you setting up the Scanner. Also I'm not entirely clear on the result you want. Do you want 2 strings for 37 with no quotes??

Comment: And what is your desired result? Three strings, lengths 2, 2, and 1, with values `37`, `37`, and ` ` (a single space)?

Comment: real sentence is 37 37  " "
the result are fromVert is 37, toVert is 37 and weight is  withe-space
I used useDelimeter("\\s+|\".\"") but it's not working please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()){

            String data = inFile.hasNextLine();
            if(!data.isEmpty()) {
                int i = data.indexOf('"');
                String sentance = data.substring(0,i);
                String betweenQuote = data.substring(i+1, data.length()-1);
                String[] verts = sentance.split(" ");
                fromVert = verts[0];
                toVert = verts[1];
                weight = betweenQuote;
            }
    }
```

You probably dont want use Next() <-- because this skip the white space automatically. Instead use NextLine() which will include white space. Then probably do some string manipulation usually this will resolve your issues.

Comment: thank you 
I didn't know that String type can be Generic type